# Advice on the best way to find intersection of two dictionaries

Tags: python, csv, python-3.7

I have posted a similar question before, but after reworking the project, I've gotten here:

With two csv files (**new.csv**, **scrapers.csv**) -

**new.csv** contains a single column:
**'urls'** = whole URLs
[image: sampleinput]

**scrapers.csv** contains two columns:
**'scraper_dom'** = A simplification of specific URL domains
**'scraper_id'** = An associated scraper_id that is used to import URLs to a separately managed database

[image: scrapers.csv]

### Question

My goal here is to iterate through **new.csv** (parsing out `fnetloc` using `urlparse`) and perform a *lookup* on **scrapers.csv** to return a set of matching **'scraper_id'** given a set of **'urls'** (the way a VLOOKUP would work, or a JOIN in SQL), once `urlparse` does it's thing to isolate the netloc within the URL (the result of `fnetloc`).

My next big issue is that `urlparse` does not parse the URLs (from **new.csv**) to the exact simplification found in the **scrapers.csv** file, so I'd be reliant on a sort of *partial match* until I can figure out the regular expressions to use for that part of it.

I've imported `pandas` because previous attempts found me creating DataFrames and performing a `pd.merge` but I couldn't get that to work either...

Current code, commented out bits at the bottom are failed attempts, just thought I'd include what I've tried thus far.
(`##` are just intermediate `print` lines I put in to check output of the program)

```
import pandas as pd, re
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import csv
sd = {}
sid = {}
#INT = []
def fnetloc(any):
    try:
        p = urlparse(any)
        return p.netloc
    except IndexError:
        return 'Error'
def dom(any):
    try:
        r = any.split(',')
        return r[0]
    except IndexError:
        return 'Error'
def ids(any):
    try:
        e = any.split(',')
        return e[0]
    except IndexError:
        return 'Error'

with open('scrapers.csv',encoding='utf-8',newline='') as s:
    reader = enumerate(csv.reader(s))
    s.readline()
    for j, row in reader:
        dict1 = dict({'scraper_dom':dom(row[0]), 'scraper_id':ids(row[1])})
        sid[j + 1] = dict1
for di in sid.keys():
    id = di
    ##print(sid[di]['scraper_dom'],sid[di]['scraper_id'])

with open('new.csv',encoding='UTF-8',newline='') as f:
    reader = enumerate(csv.reader(f))
    f.readline()
    for i, row in reader:
        dict2 = dict({'scraper_domain': fnetloc(row[0])})
        sd[i + 1] = dict2
for d in sd.keys():
    id = d
    ##print(sd[d]['scraper_domain'])

    #def tryme(  ):
        #return filter(sd.has_key, sid)
    #print(list(filter(sid, sd.keys())))
```

Sample of desired output.

[image: sampleoutput]

Comment: Can you give an example of the type of input you are processing, and the desired output?

Comment: Added sample input data and result of `fnetloc`, the url parsing function, as well as a sample of **'scrapers.csv'** that the lookup is to be performed on. Sample output also added at end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a procedure that can take a fnetloc and a list of scrapers and check to see if there is a scraper that matches that fnetloc:

```
def fnetloc_to_scraperid(fnetloc: str, scrapers: List[Scraper]) -> str:
    try:
        return next(x.scraper_id for x in scrapers if x.matches(fnetloc))
    except:
        return "[no scraper id found]"
```

I also recommend that you use some classes instead of keeping everything in csv row objects--it reduces errors in your code, in the long run, and greatly advances your sanity.

This script worked on the sample data I fed it:

```
import csv
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from typing import List

def fnetloc(any) -> str:
    try:
        p = urlparse(any)
        return p.netloc
    except IndexError:
        return 'Error'

class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, scraper_dom: str, scraper_id: str):
        self.scraper_dom = scraper_dom
        self.scraper_id = scraper_id
    def matches(self, fnetloc: str) -> bool:
        return fnetloc.endswith(self.scraper_dom)


class Site:
    def __init__(self, url: str):
        self.url = url
        self.fnetloc = fnetloc(url)
    def get_scraperid(self, scrapers: List[Scraper]) -> str:
        try:
            return next(x.scraper_id for x in scrapers if x.matches(self.fnetloc))
        except:
            return "[no scraper id found]"

sites = [Site(row[0]) for row in csv.reader(open("new.csv"))]
scrapers = [Scraper(row[0], row[1]) for row in csv.reader(open("scrapers.csv"))]

for site in sites:
    print(site.url, site.get_scraperid(scrapers), sep="\t")
```

Comment: Wow, thanks @jgfoot! I didn’t realize I was so far off the mark. Everything I had found while researching this, suggesting using a lookup between dictionaries and their key, value pairs. That or pandas.merge like I posted in my original question. 

To tackle the partial match issue, could I introduce another class with the regex values?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using pandas or database query languages for this, but I gave you the more pure-python implementation.  For larger data sets, my script won't work well--it reads the entire dataset into memory.  For bigger stuff, you'd probably want it in a database and use SQL or something to write your query.

Comment: Ok, thank you. My end goal is to deploy this as a web app using Flask for my coworkers to use. Ideally, they could copy/paste a large list of URLs from Excel into a webform, hit 'Submit' and be given the appropriate URL->scraper_id set they need to upload into a separate tool.

Writing the Flask app is a whole different challenge.